# Selenium WebDriver - hidden select and anchor

Tags: selenium, select, drop-down-menu, webdriver

I'm having a big problem with select on one page.

Code:

```
<select name="fw3k_ad_input_et_type_group" class="" 
            id="_id_fw3k_ad_input_et_type_group" 
            onchange=" eurotax.change_type_group( this.value ); " 
            style="display: none; ">

        <option value="0"> --- odaberite tip --- </option>
        <option value="-1" class="special">> nema mog tipa  </option>
        <option value="16390">CD</option>
        <option value="17605">S</option>
        <option value="17636">SE</option>

</select>
<a href="" class="fs_item" id="fs_item_0" style=""> --- odaberite tip --- </a>
```

Select is hidden and a href="" is visible part that changes its text depending on a selected option.

I don't know how to manage that. I can get all options with JavascriptExecutor and I can use a.click() to view dropdown box but I don't know how to click on some option.

I have tried to use Select class and .getOptions() method but it doesn't work with hidden select and I cannot change `<a href="">` text.

Comment: What element are you trying to click? Selenium won't interact with hidden elements.

Comment: I have options in my list [--- odaberite tip ---, CD, S, SE, > nema mog tipa] and I need to select for example "CD" and do similar to select.selectByVisibleText("CD"); (Choose option and click) See: http://imageshack.us/f/7/screenshotfrom201209111.png/

Comment: Most probably, it is possible by using JavaScript

Answer (score 3):

A little confused with the question but have you you tried

```java
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("fw3k_ad_input_et_type_group"));
Select select = new Select(element);
```

Then use either

```java
select.selectByValue(value);
select.selectByVisibleText(text);
select.selectByIndex(index);
```

Comment: I can't use Select select = new Select(element); Exception: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

Comment: Select is not visible. It works in the background. Anchor is visible part and it changes its text depending on a selected option!

Comment: Are you using jQuery for the page under test?  If so you could use the JavascriptExecutor and execute $("#_id_fw3k_ad_input_et_type_group").val('16390');

Comment: I did solve this with JavascriptExecutor! JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;    js.executeScript("document.getElementById('_id_fw3k_ad_input_et_type_group').style.display='';");

Answer (score 3):

**1st way:**
it is not the problem to click any element using the same js. As you know how to get any option the last actions remaning is to perform a click.
This should work for you:

```
WebElement hiddenWebElement =driver.findElement(By(..selector of the element....));
        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()",hiddenWebElement);
```

**2nd way**:

```
String cssSelector= ...//i gave them in your previous question
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("var x = $(\'"+cssSelector+"\');");
        stringBuilder.append("x.click();");
        js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
```

**3rd way:**
using actions builder, advanced user actions API. You can read about it [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AdvancedUserInteractions)
And code will be smth like that:

```
WebElement mnuElement;
WebElement submnuElement;
mnEle = driver.findElement(By.Id("mnEle")).click();
sbEle = driver.findElement(By.Id("sbEle")).click();

Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
// Move cursor to the Main Menu Element
builder.moveToElement(mnEle).Perform();
// Giving 5 Secs for submenu to be displayed
Thread.sleep(5000L);
// Clicking on the Hidden SubMenu
driver.findElement(By.Id("sbEle")).click();
```

You can also some additional info [here](http://www.anitpatel.net/2012/02/25/selenium-webdriver-how-to-click-on-a-hidden-link-or-menu/)
Hope this somehow helps you)

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.findElement(By.name("_id_fw3k_ad_input_et_type_group")).sendKeys("16390");
```

worked for me for something very similar.

Comment: Nice try, but exception appears: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

Comment: thank you Stilltorik it worked in my case...