# Selenium Webdriver: Select with display none

Tags: selenium

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Selenium WebDriver - hidden select and anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371228/selenium-webdriver-hidden-select-and-anchor)

Before I post my question I just want to tell that I am new to Selenium..
I am trying to select an option from a dropdown. The options display when clicked on the down arrow in the dropdown box. But, when checked in the Firebug, the display style was "none" and when trying to select the option using JUnit webdriver code by using click method in Eclipse, it did not work and it gave the exception - "org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with".

Please refer to the attached image for the dropdown and HTML tags.

```
<select class="size-dropdown mediumSelect selectBox" name="skuAndSize" style="display: none;">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="2545672:S" name="skuId"> S</option>
<option value="2545673:M" name="skuId"> M</option![enter image description here][1]>
<option value="2545674:L" name="skuId"> L</option>
<option value="2545675:XL" name="skuId"> XL</option>
<option value="2545676:XXL" name="skuId"> XXL</option>
<option value="2545677:XXXL" name="skuId"> XXXL</option>
<option value="2545678:XXXXL" name="skuId"> XXXXL</option>
</select>
```

I looked at this link before posting this question - [Selenium WebDriver - hidden select and anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371228/selenium-webdriver-hidden-select-and-anchor)
But, since I am just starting I am not able to understand clearly.

Note: The same worked in IDE when used clickAt method. But in Webdriver the clickAt method is not present. Can anyone help me in this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well the matter is Selenium is unable to interact with invisible ( disabled) elemnts. So you need to make element visible. BAsic idea: to make dropdown roll down , then wait with `driver.manage.timeout(...)` and then click on the appear needed element in dropdown.
Or you can use javascript to click element directly without preceeding dropdown roll down. Js is able to cope with it.

So **this approach ALWAYS works**:

```
css1=select[class="size-dropdown mediumSelect selectBox"]>option[value=""]
css2=select[class="size-dropdown mediumSelect selectBox"]>option[value="2545672:S"]
css2=select[class="size-dropdown mediumSelect selectBox"]>option[value="value="2545673:M"]
//.... and so on.....
public void jsClickOn(String cssSelector){
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("var x = $(\'"+cssSelector+"\');");
        stringBuilder.append("x.click();");
        js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
}
jsClickOn(css1);
jsClickOn(css2);
jsClickOn(css3);
```

Another way:
 using actions builder, advanced user actions API. You can read about it [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AdvancedUserInteractions) And code will be smth like that:

```
WebElement mnuElement;
WebElement submnuElement;
mnEle = driver.findElement(By.Id("mnEle")).click();
sbEle = driver.findElement(By.Id("sbEle")).click();

Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
// Move cursor to the Main Menu Element
builder.moveToElement(mnEle).Perform();
// Giving 5 Secs for submenu to be displayed
Thread.sleep(5000L);
// Clicking on the Hidden SubMenu
driver.findElement(By.Id("sbEle")).click();
```

But also pay attention on the way how you found css selectors, xpaths verifying it in e.g. firepath, addon to firebug in ffox.
[image]
Hope this helps you)

See this screen as example of locating dropdown options.
[image: dropdownOptions]

Comment: Thanks for your reply.When I tried to get the CSS for the options using Firepath,it displayed same path for all options. Also, when selected that option,this time it was pointing to a different tag <ul> and <li>. I tried to attach an image here.. but not sure how to do it..

Comment: i've added one more screen. You can email me: eugene.polschikov@gmail.com  or skype me: eugene.polschikov
you are unable to attach screens yet as you do no have enough rate(points) on stackoverflow