# A way of clicking on hidden elements in protractor end to end tests

Tags: angularjs, protractor

Is there a way to click on a hidden value in a sub menu. I would like to be able to do something like

```
driver.findElement(protractor.By.xpath('/html/body/div/div/a')).mouseover.then(function() {
    ptor.findElement(protractor.By.className('name').getText().then(function(result) {
        expect(result).toBe('Me');
    });
});
```

when the menu item is not visible, or are we limited with this at the moment. If this is not possible is there a way around this issue at present.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ok so after a long and painful search trying to find an answer to this question I finally came across the answer trying to answer a different question.

Most of the documentation I found explain that we must use Actions in the form of a WebElement and then cast that to Javascript and pass it a script element in the form of an array with the click action.

Well the same kinds goes here but with a few modifications.

```
describe('', function() {
    var ptor = protractor.getInstance();
    var driver = ptor.driver;

    it('', function() {
        var hiddenElement = driver.findElement(protractor.By.yourchosenlocator(''));
        driver.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", hiddenElement).then(function() {
            expect(whatever).toMatch(whatever);
        });
    }, 30000);
});
```

as you can see there is no use of webelement and no cast required.

Here are the sources that helped me in my search for answers

[How do you click on an element which is hidden using Selenium Webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17448141/how-do-you-click-on-an-element-which-is-hidden-using-selenium-webdriver)

[SELENIUM WEBDRIVER – HOW TO CLICK ON A HIDDEN LINK OR MENU](http://www.anitpatel.net/2012/02/25/selenium-webdriver-how-to-click-on-a-hidden-link-or-menu/)

[Selenium WebDriver - hidden select and anchor [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371228/selenium-webdriver-hidden-select-and-anchor)

Comment: I tried many variations but can't get this to work. I'm doing `driver.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", element( by.css( '.logout' ) ) )` and it results in `UnknownError: {"errorMessage":"'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'arguments[0].click()')"`

Comment: what version of protractor are you using? newer version may require you to use ptor.executeScript or protractor.executeScript. could you post your code so I can see it and I may be able to help you from there

Comment: I was able to find it on `browser.executeScript` from the docs. https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md#how-can-i-interact-directly-with-the-javascript-running-in-my-app.

I get a little confused when to use `ptor`, `driver` and `browser`... there are tons of examples out there that seem to mix them around a bit.

Comment: It's because of the updated versions of protractor. However I believe it is pretty stable now so there shouldn't be much deviation from the syntax as it matures.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on to the accepted answer, the below code worked for me.

Import statement:

```
import { browser, by, element } from 'protractor';
```

Code:

```
const hiddenElement = element(by.id('hiddenIcon'));
browser.driver.executeScript('arguments[0].click();', hiddenElement.getWebElement());
```

Just change the `hiddenIcon` to the id of your element.

Instead of using

> var ptor = protractor.getInstance(); var driver = ptor.driver;

we can also use

> browser.driver