# Selecting hidden elements when using protractorjs with phantomjs

Tags: angularjs, phantomjs, protractor

In a recent post of mine I had an issue with hideen elements (see [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406674/a-way-of-clicking-on-hidden-elements-in-protractor-end-to-end-tests)). Since then I have moved from chrome driver to phantomjs for headless testing.

My issue is this.

Since the move selecting hidden elements causes the **error** below,

> UnknownError: Error Message => ''undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'arguments[0].click()')'

Running in chrome (webdriver) is fine and all test pass but phantomjs doesn't seem to like this method. Is there another way round this issue that will run in under test using `phantomjs` and `protractorjs`.

**EDIT**
The test below is what I am having issues

```
it('should redirect to addresses', function () {
        var hiddenWebElement = ptor.driver.findElement(by.css('ul#myaccount li:nth-child(2) a'));
        ptor.driver.executeScript("arguments[0].click()",hiddenWebElement).then(function() {
            expect(ptor.driver.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('#/addresses');
        });
    }, 15000);
```

my config file is

```
// An example configuration file.
exports.config = {
    // The address of a running selenium server.
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:52254',
    // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'phantomjs'
    },

    // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directly when
    // protractor is called.
    specs: [
        'Scenarios/account_spec.js',
        'Scenarios/add_address_spec.js'
    ],

    // Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
    }
};
```

A point to notice is that all tests above this run expect the one below which again has an issue when trying to find the element

```
it('should redirect to login', function () {
        ptor.driver.findElement(by.id('headerLoginBtn')).click().then(function () {
            expect(ptor.driver.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('/Account/Login');
        });
    }, 15000);
```

which throws an exception of element is not visible. Also my tests in this scenario use ptor.driver because the pages contain c# ASP.NET code.

Comment: Can you share more of your test code? The error looks like something is wrong in your test, not an error coming from webdriver.

Comment: Out of interest, why do you want to click hidden elements?  Protractor testing is intended to replicate user behaviour, and users can't click hidden elements.  (I'm not saying that tools cannot be used for alternative purposes, though)

Comment: I have a button that activates a dropdown menu and until the button is hovered over the menu does not appear. hence the requirement for selecting hidden elements.

Comment: Jmr, the test is fine as it runs under chrome via webdriver, just not under phantomjs.

Comment: i have the same problem. works on firefox not phantomjs. did u solve it?

Comment: no not yet been able to fix this issue. will update when I have though

Comment: thank you for the reply. i managed to get it working by removing the css that made it hidden.

Answer (score 0):

i found a workaround which looks like the only possible way to me. I removed the css that hide the element and then clicked on it and it worked. I am using selenium but it should be similar solution for you

```
    executeJavaScript("$('.log-out').removeClass('hide');");
    driver.findElement(By.className("log-out")).click();
```