# Protractor - Can't click on invisible "ng-click" element

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, automation, jasmine, protractor

I've problematic element that I can't click on him by Protractor.

Actually it was fine util a few days ago.

**Technical details:**

Chrome 47.0.2526.106 m

Protractor 2.0

Selenium 2.44

**CSS**

```
<button class="green-btn font-xs md-button ng-scope md-ink-ripple" type="button" ng-transclude="" ng-click="reply()" ng-disabled="inProgress" translate="conversation.page_action.send" aria-disabled="false">Send<div class="md-ripple-container"></div></button>
```

**Test case:**

```
it('vCita New App - Conversation - Reply to existing conversation - Message sent', function() {
     browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.css('[ng-click="reply()"]'))), 30000);
     element(by.css('[ng-click="reply()"]')).click();
});
```

**Error:**

```
ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible (Session info: chrome=47.0.2526.106) (Driver info: chromedriver=2.14.313457 (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9cf),platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 24 milliseconds Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50' System info: host: 'vCitaQA', ip: '192.168.152.1', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_65' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\idan\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir10416_32044}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=47.0.2526.106, platform=WIN8_1, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}] Session ID: e0c5329c3e1f187094ca7d9f76374c7c at new bot.Error (c:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\error.js:113:18) at Object.bot.response.checkResponse (c:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\response.js:106:9) at c:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:377:20 at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (c:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1877:20) at [object Object].promise.Callback_.goog.defineClass.notify (c:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:2464:25) at [object Object].promise.Promise.notify_ (c:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:563:12) at Array.forEach (native) at Object.goog.array.forEach (c:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\array\array.js:203:43) at [object Object].promise.Promise.notifyAll_ (c:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:552:16) at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (c:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:125:21) Error at [object Object].ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (c:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:403:21) at [object Object].self.(anonymous function) [as click] (c:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:76:19) at [object Object].self.(anonymous function) [as click] (c:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:733:11) at [object Object]. (C:\automation\tests\testCases\newApp\conversationTC.js:30:40) at c:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd\index.js:94:14 at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (c:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1877:20) at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runEventLoop_ (c:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1755:8) at [object Object]. (c:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:2056:12) at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (c:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:125:21) at runMicrotasksCallback (node.js:337:7) From: Task: Asynchronous test function: it() at [object Object]. (c:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd\index.js:93:33) at [object Object]. (c:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\async-callback.js:45:37) at [object Object].jasmine.Block.execute (c:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:1174:17) at [object Object].jasmine.Queue.next_ (c:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2209:31) at [object Object].jasmine.Queue.start (c:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2162:8) at [object Object].jasmine.Spec.execute (c:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2503:14) at [object Object].jasmine.Queue.next_ (c:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2209:31) at onComplete (c:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2205:18) at [object Object].jasmine.Spec.finish (c:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2477:5) at [object Object].onComplete (c:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2504:10)==== async task ==== Error at [object Object]. (C:\automation\tests\testCases\newApp\conversationTC.js:27:4) at [object Object].jasmine.Env.describe_ (c:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:913:21) at [object Object].jasmine.Env.describe (c:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:898:15) at describe (c:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:658:27) at Object. (C:\automation\tests\testCases\newApp\conversationTC.js:1:63) at Module._compile (module.js:460:26) at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10) at Module.load (module.js:355:32) at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
```

Comment: Is your button invisible? I don't see hidden attribute on it. Protractor always waits until element is visible to click on it, so if you want to click on your invisible element [check this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18504920/4180674). Also your protractor and selenium-webdriver versions are outdated. Please update them and try again to see if it resolves your issue. Thanks

Comment: I've updated the npm, protractor, selenium webdriver, chromedriver & jdk now. but it doesn't fix this use case.
Any another idea to handle this issue? thanks @GirishSortur

Comment: Are you sure there are no other elements having `ng-click="reply()"`?

Comment: @GirishSortur You should put that in an answer because it it 100% correct.

Comment: It seems like it's the only element in this page but the log in protractor warn about more.. But I've already tried by class & translate and it doesn't work as well. @alecxe

Comment: @IdanE try using other element locators that points to the exact element that you want to click, for ex - `element(by.buttonText('Send'));`, this might resolve your issue.

Comment: @GirishSortur Thanks, but I've tried your suggestion and it still fail with the same error - "ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible. :/ 
What happens there?

Comment: @IdanE is your application in public domain and you can share with us? Also element is not clickable because of 2 reasons, its either somewhere down in the DOM and not visible on the screen or its hidden completely with hidden attribute. Does your element belong to any of those categories? Thanks

Comment: The element is visible in the view (it's the SEND green button in the bottom of the screen) - head to http://app.vcita.com , login by user: stackoverflow@vcita.com , pass: 111111 and then head to the page below: https://app.vcita.com/app/conversations/harcgk7ediyz8zt1
@GirishSortur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are you sure there are no other elements having `ng-click="reply()"`?

Judging by the source code of the provided page, this is exactly the case. *There are two elements having `ng-click="reply()"`* and the first one is disabled which means you cannot interact with it. You need the second element:

```
$$('[ng-click="reply()"]').last().click();
```

You may also improve your selector to match the element inside the button bar:

```
$('.actions-bar > [ng-click="reply()"]').click();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You're a brilliant as always! @alecxe