# Upload file to hidden field in WedriverIO Using CucumerJS

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, cucumber, cucumberjs

Hi I need to automate a website using cucumberJS and webdriverIO. For that I need to Upload a file but the field is hidden. For Example :

```
<input type="file" id='uploadFile' style="display: none"'>
```

but webdriver is unable to identify the element on the UI.

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selenium WebDriver - hidden select and anchor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371228/selenium-webdriver-hidden-select-and-anchor)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got the solution for this Issue.Using webdriverIO we can execute javascript to change the style display from "none" to "block".

```
client.execute(function() {
document.getElementById("element_id").style.display="block";
},function(err) {
client.uploadFile(localPath[,callback])    
if(err){
console.log("Error "+err);
}
});
```

then upload the file to the field and then change the display again to none.

Comment: This won't work when it is the parent element thats hidden

Answer (score 8):

In webdriverIO v5, files are uploaded to inputs of `type="file"` by calling `.setValue()` on them with the local file path as an argument. This doesn't seem to work for hidden inputs though, because `.setValue()` first calls `.clearValue()` which will throw `Element could not be scrolled into view`. To work around this, call `.addValue()` directly on the element:

```
input.addValue(filePath);
```

Relevant API docs: https://webdriver.io/docs/api/element/addValue.html

Comment: Spent a lot of time with this bug. Same issue, our Error was Element not interactable though.

Tried all the browser.execute solutions I could find and none worked to change the display of the hidden element. This did the trick though for us!

Comment: For me "addValue" gives error as "stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document" and "setValue" gives "element not interactable" error

Comment: @TerribleDeveloper Stale element reference is a [different issue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Errors/StaleElementReference). You'd need to address that before this has a chance at working.